# @media query doesn't work on ipad portrait (already searched all questions)

Tags: html, css, ipad, media-queries

Evening all, I am having a problem in media queries for ipad portrait here is my code.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait){//CSS HERE }
```

I tried using `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`, I also tried using `only screen` and `all` in my queries. I also added viewports

```
<meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

However it's still not working on iPad portrait, keep in mind that all other media queries are working but this. Even when testing, using the inspect element it isn't taking the media queries into consideration.

Any help?

Comment: is it an iPad Pro?

Comment: no talking here about iPad and even testing it on responsive web viewer nothing

Comment: May be dumb suggestion: But confirm that the css your ipad browser loaded is the most recent css with your changes. Sometimes browser will cache the css files.

Comment: I tried this after clearing cache I did find the answer to my question by fiddling around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

After some fiddling around I found out that it would be easier for me to use this

```
@media (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 799px){//CSS HERE}
```

I read somewhere that it is better to do for resolutions rather than devices

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the other media queries on your page are overriding the styles from this one (if the breakpoints overlap)? Try commenting out your other queries and see if this one works?

Comment: no when it is on 768x1024 portrait no media queries are showing in the inspect element, only the normal ones